# Wordpress Options-Theme STD (default) value does not work

Tags: plugins, theme-options

I'm using [Wordpress Options Theme](http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/) and I'm getting an issue.

Here's the code:

```
$options[] = array( "name" => __('Texto de bot&oacute;n de enlace a cotizaci&oacute;n',THEMENAME),
                    "desc" => __('Inserta el texto que aparecer&aacute; en los botones de cotizaci&oacute;n',THEMENAME),
                    "id" => "ns_custom_caps_quote_btn",
                    "std" => __('Cotizar', THEMENAME),
                    "type" => "text");
```

And when I reset to default, the input returns "a" instead of "Cotizar".

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the CONSTANT for? Should just be `"std" => "default value"`

Comment: It does not work neither. The constant is for internationalisation purposes. I stripped the function __() and put the plain string and does not work neither.

Comment: Have you tried hitting "restore defaults" button on the options page? Reason I say this is that you can save an "empty" string in the instance of this framework so the default only applys when there is no value saved for that given field.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without seeing your *entire* Theme Settings implementation. Can you edit the question to include *all* relevant code, or link to a Pastebin or similar that contains the code?

Comment: @ChipBennett To clarify he is using: http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/ - I only know because I'm using the same one on a particular project and know the behavior he is describing.

Comment: Call me crazy. I opened the code one more time, added a new input just for testing and it's working perfectly fine now. I'm wondering if the fact that I have upgraded the library breaks something in the process. It's working now and I appreciate a lot all your help fellows. Cheers.

Comment: Ok, your crazy.

Comment: Jajajaja! :D I asked for, I can't complain about it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values set in the 'std' key of the array,

```
'std' => 'your default value'
```

Are saved to the database on first initialization of the framework.

Once you overwrite the default value and or remove the default value, even if left as a blank field, the default no longer applies unless you hit the "restore defaults" button.

Comment: I'ts working now userabuser. Thanks a lot. I will check this as solved using your answer if you don't mind.

Comment: No problem, you will observe that the behavior I describe is in fact correct anyway when you go ahead and edit your fields. Watch how the defaults don't restore themselves unless you intervene by hitting the restore button. All the best.

Comment: Ok, I have taked note of your recommendation. I will upload now to final server and I hope it works fine, as in the local server. Thanks again!